# Android Thread & AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a code placed in the `onActivityResult()` but it is slowing my activity alot,
the code is to do Binarizng on Image.
I am confused whats to use `AsyncTask` or `Thread`,
can you help me with it

Comment: AsyncTask wrap an Executor, that allow to run task on a thread != the UI Thread. It hides a low level constructor providing a more userfrendly interface

Comment: Thank you I used the AsyncTask .... it gives me 100& performance improve and without error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onActivityResult has nothing to do with threads or async tasks.

A thread allows your app to do two things at once.  Doing so can be fairly risky (what if they write the same variables at the same time?).  You need to be careful when using them.

An AsyncTask is a Thread that will automatically run some code on the main UI thread when its done.  Its useful for running some code on a thread and then synchronizing results on the main thread.

onActivityResult is called when you are running a completely separate activity, either in your own app or in another person's.  If you need to run another activity, this is the only way to get a result back from it.  It has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: Thank you I used the AsyncTask .... it gives me 100& performance improve and without errors

Comment: i used it in the on activity result

Answer (score 1):

Use AsyncTask

AsyncTask Also uses Thread, but in a intelligent way. In android you can not update UI directly from a worker thread. But you can perform UI tasks from Asynctask. So this is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Both AsyncTask and Thread, let you run background task on a different thread.

But AsyncTask provide you various callback, so that you can Update UI once the   background task is done Or Canceled.

So, if your task involve any UI update; please use AsyncTask.